# Constructing measures with support in a given set

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, fractals

I've recently come across the Frostmann Lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frostman_lemma). Its proof involves constructing a measure with certain properties on a given subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (I'm primarily interested in $n=1$ and compact subsets).

I'm interested in finding similar results, i.e. starting with some subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{R}^n$), maybe some additional parameters and then constructing a measure with specific properties on that set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is too broad. What are "specific properties"?
All sorts of equilibrium measures from potential theory quality.

Here is an example of a deep result: on every compact set in $R^n$ there exists a non-zero
measure satisfying the doubling condition, which means that the measure of every ball
is at most constant times the measure of twice smaller ball with the same center.
MR0765294.

Comment: Thanks, that example is precisely the kind of result I'm looking for. As I am not planning to invoke such a result, I can't really specify more what I want.